# maven-assembly "Unable to create directory or parent directory" on Linux

Tags: maven

I have a project with 3 differents modules with Maven, but one of the module fail every time with a weird error.

I thouhght it can be a plugin error (maven-assembly-plugin), i tried pretty much everythings i can think of, redownload the dependencies, clean, install, editing the pom to be as simple as possible...

The build on this module works fine on Windows (10), but not on Linux (CentOs) :(

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single (my-package) on project my-module: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bundle-oozie: Unable to create directory or parent directory of /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/project/my-module/target/my-package/my-package/../../23321.project.seq -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single (my-package) on project my-module: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bundle-oozie: Unable to create directory or parent directory of /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/project/my-module/target/my-package/my-package/../../23321.project.seq
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bundle-oozie: Unable to create directory or parent directory of /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/project/my-module/target/my-package/my-package/../../23321.project.seq
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:532)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.mojos.SingleAssemblyMojo.execute(SingleAssemblyMojo.java:61)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.archive.ArchiveCreationException: Error creating assembly archive bundle-oozie: Unable to create directory or parent directory of /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/project/my-module/target/my-package/my-package/../../23321.project.seq
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:188)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:478)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiverException: Unable to create directory or parent directory of /home/myuser/IdeaProjects/project/my-module/target/my-package/my-package/../../23321.project.seq
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.dir.DirectoryArchiver.copyFile(DirectoryArchiver.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.dir.DirectoryArchiver.execute(DirectoryArchiver.java:98)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:987)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:445)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:184)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: How is the assembly plugin configured?

Comment: Wow, i can't believe i'm this stupid, it was in fact an error in the assembly-bundle... I don't know why it work on Windows but not on linux tho. but Thank you !